# How to save server rendered page to a custom static folder for later use in next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm creating a real estate website.
I'm using Next.Js as framework for react.
To optimise my system, I want to create a system such that:-
On first request of main page from client side, server should serve some basic data and redux, then using redux, I want to call api, recieve data and further render some same kind components on client side. Then I want to attach a functionality to the components such that, on click it checks the requested page on a custom static folder, if it is available then serve it statically to client, if not then rendered the page on server by taking data stored in redux and copy the static version of page to custom static folder and serve to client. I also want to make a function which continuosly checks on the static files expiry and update.
Problem is I'm unable to achieve the functionality of storing chunks of page statically on a custom folder, and creating check function for it on Next.Js
-------->>>>>>>>>>>>
Attaching rough image of system.

[Rough Image of system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg1jM.jpg)
-------->>>>>>>>>>>>>
Any help or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is way too broad. You might want to review [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Without writing the whole explanation, no one will understand the question.

Comment: The problem is not the explanation but it would be useful to share the relevant code and be specific about the request. Right now, your question is of the type "*I want to obtain this, how can I do?*" while it should be "*I want to obtain this, **I am trying in this way** (show relevent code) but **I got stuck here** (share any error message or unexpected behaviour); how can I solve that particular bit?*"

Comment: Because it's is not the problem of errors in code, it is the problem of concept and technique. Please read the whole question and see the image attached herewith to understand.

Comment: Have you given [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) a look? Sounds similar to what you're trying to achieve, but comes out-of-the-box in Next.js.

Comment: Yes, but problem in that is, I cannot delete static page by a user action or delete automatic if not in use

Comment: Also with the updation.